# Is there a way to switch the Search form (used in the block) to do a Facet Search instead?

Tags: search

I am using [Faceted Navigation for Search](https://drupal.org/project/search_facetapi) and I want to switch the standard Search block to do a faceted search directly rather than the current situation where I have to switch to faceted search after the standard block shows up.

Is there a module for that, or can it be fixed somewhere in the options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated below I originally understood your question.  Here is how you change the default search page to the one with faceted navigation:
In admin/config/search/settings you can turn off default node search and make faceted your default as shown in the below screen shot.
[image]

The [Search API module](https://drupal.org/project/search_api) allows you to choose other search methods, including using something like SOLR server for search, which also does faceted queries.

Comment: I am talking about getting the default Search form (ie the one used in the block) to do a faceted search, or whether there is a facet related module that can provide is own Search form that can be placed in the block.

Comment: The Search API module in conjunction with Custom Search module and SOLR search module will allow you to use the default search block to do faceted search.

Comment: A way to get around all of this would be to use Views exposed filter and combined fields, though this will slow down as the site becomes larger.  I would recommend using Search API + SOLR server and module.

Comment: I am not using the Search API or Solr. Is it possible without these?

Comment: I think I originally miss-udnerstood your question.  I now understand it as you only want to change your default search page to the faceted navigation search page.  I am updating my answer with a screenshot to provide you with help.

Comment: I had set it like that before and it wasn't working. I checked it again it looks okay now. Perhaps some caching or some other related settings was affecting it

Comment: Yes it is usually a good idea to flush drupal and browser cache after changing settings if you don't see a change.